# Passing a symbol to a helper function in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to move this part of my form into a helper method?

```
<%= f.label :address do %>
  <%= f.object.class.human_attribute_name :address %>
  <span>optional</span>
<% end %><br/>
```

I have a number of occasions where I need the `span` but I don't know how to pass the `:address` symbol into a helper function.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: do you want to move the whole? You should move the whole thing if you gonna use this whole part in some other places..

Comment: If you want to reuse this entire block, perhaps a partial (using the :locals option to set a local variable for the symbol) would make more sense?

Comment: OK thanks, so I am going to use a partial here. Just out of curiosity: Why wouldn't it make sense to move this into a helper function here? Is it not possible to pass symbols to helper functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might implement this part of view as partial which can be recycled everythere you need it see [Layouts and Renderings](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

You can pass variables towards Partials as described in 3.4.4 Passing Local Variables